# magento2 Changing shipping method does not update payment method java script code

Tags: knockout.js, magento2, payment, gateway

I created a custom payment method in Magento2. My payment form will display many payment gateways. Each one has a different payment service charge and a different gateway currency. What I need is to reload the payment form each time I change the shipping method to recalculate the payment new amounts.

The below code is for how I detect the selected shipping method in my custom js.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $(document).on("click", '#checkout-step-shipping_method input', function () {
      // here, I need to reload the payment form to recalculate the payment new amounts
   });
});
```

Steps to reproduce

1. Enable my custom payment method.
2. Add a product to the cart.
3. Go to the checkout page, and my custom payment js file is loaded.
4. The total cost will be calculated according to the current select
   shipping method.
5. Click the Next Button: my payment method shows a list of available
   gateways with their total cost and the gateways currencies.
6. Go back to the Shipping page.
7. Change the shipping methods.
8. Click the Next button; the gateways list is not updated because the
   javascript file is not updated.

How to fix this issue?